# Python: Pandas merge leads to NaN

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I'm trying to execute a merge with pandas. The two files have a common key ("KEY_PLA") which I'm trying to use with a left join. But unfortunately, all columns which are transferred from the second file to the first file have NaN values.

Here is what I have done so far:

```
df_1 = pd.read_excel(path1, skiprows=1)
df_2 = pd.read_excel(path2, skiprows=1)

df_1.columns = ["Index", "KEY", "KEY_PLA", "INFO1", "INFO2"]
df_2.columns = ["Index", "KEY_PLA", "INFO4"]

df_1.drop(["Index"], axis=1, inplace=True)
df_2.drop(["Index"], axis=1, inplace=True)

# Merge all dataframes
df_merge = pd.DataFrame()

df_merge = df_1.merge(df_2, left_on="KEY_PLA", right_on="KEY_PLA", how="left")
print(df_merge)
```

This is the result:[image: Result]

Here are the excel files:

[Excel1](https://ufile.io/gvv43)
[Excel2](https://ufile.io/tdhnm)

What is wrong with the code? I also checked the types and even converted the columns in strings. But nothing works.

Comment: Please post `df_1.head().to_dict('list')` and `df_2.head().to_dict('list')` so we don't have to download MBs to look at this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think problem is different `type`s of joined columns `KEY_PLA`, obviously one is integer and another `string`s.

Solution is cast to same, e.g. to `int`s:

```
print (df_1['KEY_PLA'].dtype)
object

print (df_2['KEY_PLA'].dtype)
int64

df_1['KEY_PLA'] = df_1['KEY_PLA'].astype(int)
```

Comment: Thank you so much ! That works :) But why does it not work with `df_1['KEY_PLA'] = df_1['KEY_PLA'].astype(str)` and `df_2['KEY_PLA'] = df_2['KEY_PLA'].astype(str)` ?

Comment: It should working with `df_2['KEY_PLA'] = df_2['KEY_PLA'].astype(str)`, because `object` is obviously `string`

Comment: It is another possible solution :)

Comment: But it does not. It is still the result you can see on the picture above.

Comment: hmmmm, by picture seems there are traling `\n`, so need `df_1['KEY_PLA'] = df_1['KEY_PLA'].str.strip()` and `df_2['KEY_PLA'] = df_2['KEY_PLA'].astype(str)`

Comment: Ah I found the mistake. In the second file all entries include a "/n". Because of that the keys aren't equal. Thank you so much :-)